Why did Lisa leave Sosuke and Ponyo alone?
During the night of the storm, Lisa sees lights from the senior center where she works and decides she needs to leave to check on the people there.  She does this even though it leaves two five-year-olds, Sosuke and Ponyo, alone in the house with crazy weather going on.
The first time I saw the movie, I thought that the story needed some way for Sosuke and Ponyo to have an adventure on their own, and Lisa was just being impulsive and trusting that Sosuke takes following instructions very seriously even at his young age, and maybe we weren't supposed to question it.
But my mother suggested a possibility I had not considered:  that Lisa was behaving unusually because she was under a spell.  Ponyo's parents, Fujimoto and Granmamare, were arranging things because a test of Sosuke's love for Ponyo was required in order to grant her wish to become a human.  At the end of the movie, the senior center is magically protected underwater, and Fujimoto says that the people there need to serve as witnesses to the test of love.  So Lisa, who also needed to be there because she was essentially adopting Ponyo, was drawn there supernaturally.
I like that explanation, but I was wondering if there is any evidence to support it, either in the Japanese version or from Miyazaki's comments about the story.

Japan has been somewhat famous for young children going on subways, doing errands and so forth without adult supervision. In comparison, leaving someone at home for a short time while one goes to a place within line of sight seems unremarkable.
